# Find high & low peak points in cell array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to find "significant" changes in a cell array in MATLAB for when I have a movement.

E.g. I have YT which represents movements in a yaw presentation for a face interaction. YT can change based on an interaction from anywhere upwards of 80x1 to 400x1. The first few lines might be

```
YT = {-7 -8 -8 -8 -8 -9 -9 -9 -6 ...}
```

I would like to record the following

Over the entire cell array;

**1) Count the number of high and low peaks**

I can do this with findpeak but not for low peaks?*

**2) Measure the difference between each peak** -

For this example, peaks -9 and -6 so difference of +3 between those. So report 1 peak change of +3. At the moment I am only interested in changes of +/- 3, but this might change, so I will need a threshold?

and then over X number of cells (repeating for the cell array)

**3) count number of changes - for this example, 3 changes**

**3) count number of significant changes - for this example, 1 changes of -/+3**

**4) describe the change - 1 change of -1, 1 change of -1, 1 change of +3**

Any help would be appreciated, bit of a MATLAB noob.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Finding negative peaks is the same as finding positive ones - all you need to do is multiply the sequence by -1 and then findpeaks again

2) If you simply want the differences, then you could subtract the vectors of the positive and negative peaks (possibly offset by one if you want differences in both directions).  Something like `pospeaks-negpeaks` would do one side.  You'd need to identify whether the positive or negative peak was first (use the loc return from findpeaks to determine this), and then do `pospeaks(1:end-1)-negpeaks(2:end)` or vice versa as appropriate.

[edit]As pointed out in your comment, the above assumes that pospeaks and negpeaks are the same length.  I shouldn't have been so lazy!  The code might be better written as:

```
if (length(pospeaks)>length(negpeaks))
    % Starts and ends with a positive peak
    neg_diffs=pospeaks(1:end-1)-negpeaks;
    pos_diffs=negpeaks-pospeaks(2:end);
elseif (length(pospeaks)<length(negpeaks))
    % Starts and ends with a negative peak
    pos_diffs=negpeaks(1:end-1)-pospeaks;
    neg_diffs=pospeaks-negpeaks(1:end-1);
elseif posloc<negloc
    % Starts with a positive peak, and ends with a negative one
    neg_diffs=pospeaks-negpeaks;
    pos_diffs=pospeaks(2:end)-negpeaks(1:end-1);
else
    % Starts with a negative peak, and ends with a positive one
    pos_diffs=negpeaks-pospeaks;
    neg_diffs=negpeaks(2:end)-pospeaks(1:end-1);
end
```

I'm sure that could be coded more effectively, but I can't think just now how to write it more compactly.  `posloc` and `negloc` are the location returns from findpeaks.[/edit]

For (3) to (5) it is easier to record the differences between samples: `changes=[YT{2:end}]-[YT{1:end-1}];`

3) To count changes, count the number of non-zeros in the difference between adjacent elements: `sum(changes~=0)`

4) You don't define what you mean by "significant changes", but the test is almost identical to 3) `sum(abs(changes)>=3)`

5) It is simply `changes(changes~=0)`

Comment: Hi Dave,This is really useful. However I can't get pospeaks[1:end-1]-negpeaks[2:end] to run. Any ideas? I changed [ ] to () and I get a matrix dimensions error (pospeaks is 9x1, negpeaks is 10x1)

Comment: Sorry about the square brackets - I've been writing MEX files so got my C and Matlab syntax mixed up!  I must admit, I foolishly assumed you'd have as many positive as negative peaks, but obviously life is never that simple!  You'll see in the solution above that I've made a substantial edit (delimited by [edit] and [/edit]) that gives a more robust solution.  I am sure it could be written more elegantly, but at the moment I can't think how!  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `diff` is the command which can provide the basis of a solution to all your problems (prior converting the cell to an array with `cell2mat`). It outputs the difference between adjacent values along an array:

1) You'd have to define what a 'peak' is but at a guess:

```
 YT = cell2mat(YT); % convert cell to array
 change = diff(YT); % get diffs
 highp = sum(change >= 3); % high peak threshold
 lowp = sum(change <= -3); % low peak threshold
```

2) `diff(cell2mat(YT))` provides this.

3)

```
YT = cell2mat(YT); % convert cell to array
change = diff(YT); % get diffs
count = sum(change~=0);
```

4) Seems to be answered in the other points?